# NGINX proxy configuration

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a unicorn app server running a rails app and a tilestream server serving up tiles
one listens on local unix socket, and the other on 127.0.0.1:8888
here is my conifg:

```
upstream unicorn_server {
   server unix:/var/www/fulcrumapp/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock;
}

  client_header_buffer_size 128k;
  large_client_header_buffers 4 128k;

  server {
            listen 80;
            server_name servername.com;
            keepalive_timeout 30;
            root   /var/www/servername/public/;
                        location / {
                          proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                          proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                          proxy_redirect off;

                          client_max_body_size 300m;

                          if (!-f $request_filename) {
                                           proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
                                           break;
                          }
            }
}

upstream tiles {
    server 127.0.0.1:8888;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name tiles.servername.com;
    access_log /var/www/servername/log/tilestream-tiles.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/servername/log/tilestream-tiles.error.log debug;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://tiles;
    }
}
```

the first server works fine... 
the "tiles" server kicks back "bad request" 400 errors

on the local server running:
curl 127.0.0.1:8888

fetches the page as expected

hitting tiles.servername.com:8080
fails.

this is an amazon EC2 instance where the public IP is not the local server IP
but I don't think the amazon NAT layer is getting in the way.

server OS is ubuntu 11.04

debug nginx log here:
http://pastie.org/2483294

Answer (score 2):

Got it figured out, start of with:

```
tilestream server starting with --host tiles.servername.com
```

Then edit `/etc/hosts/` on the server:

```
127.0.0.1  tiles.servername.com
```

Then proxy config as above.

The "Bad Request" was coming from the tilestream server.
The `--host parameter` specifies the ONLY hosts it will accept connections from.